# How to fix "error: invalid use of non-static data member 'tree::root'" error in c++?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, arguments

I have this code below:

```c
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define DEFAULT_NODE_VALUE 0
using namespace std;


class node{
public:
    int val;
    node* right = 0;
    node* left = 0;
    node(int a):val(a){}

};

class tree{
public:
    node* root = new node(DEFAULT_NODE_VALUE);
    tree(int inp_val){
        root->val = inp_val; 
    }

    void inorder_traverse(node* temp = root){
        
    }
    
};
```

I want to make default argument for `temp` parameter in `inorder_traverse` function but
when I compiled above code, the compiler showed this:

```
22:37: error: invalid use of non-static data member 'tree::root'
17:8: note: declared here
```

Please help me to fix this. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argument defaults are not evaluated in the scope of the method. Instead of using a default argument, use overloading.

```
void inorder_traverse() {
    inorder_traverse(root);
}
void inorder_traverse(node *temp) {
    // code
}
```